# Why is recompilation of dependency needed in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a project where `hello` package imports `world` package.
I compile the `world` package then the `hello` package and
things are fine.
Now I make a trivial change to the `hello` package and try
to recompile it but it fails. I have to compile the `world`
package again and then the `hello` package.

Why do I have to compile the dependency? Why isn't compiling the dependent package sufficient?

```
$  kotlinc -version 
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.8.10 (JRE 19.0.2)

$  tree
.
├── classes
└── src
    ├── hello
    │   └── Main.kt
    └── world
        └── World.kt

5 directories, 2 files

$  cat src/hello/Main.kt 
package hello;

import world.foo;

fun main() {
    println("Hello ++ " + world.foo())
}


$  cat src/world/World.kt 
package world;

public fun foo() = "World"

$  kotlinc -d classes -cp classes src/world/World.kt 
$  kotlinc -d classes -cp classes src/hello/Main.kt 
$  kotlin -cp classes hello.MainKt
Hello ++ World
    
$  sed -i '' s/++/+++++/g src/hello/Main.kt # change main file

$  cat src/hello/Main.kt 
package hello;

import world.foo;

fun main() {
    println("Hello +++++ " + world.foo())
}

$  kotlinc -d classes -cp classes src/hello/Main.kt 
src/hello/Main.kt:3:14: error: unresolved reference: foo
import world.foo;
             ^
src/hello/Main.kt:6:33: error: unresolved reference: foo
    println("Hello +++++ " + world.foo())
                                ^
$  kotlinc -d classes -cp classes src/world/World.kt 
$  kotlinc -d classes -cp classes src/hello/Main.kt 

$  kotlin -cp classes hello.MainKt
Hello +++++ World
$
```

Comment: Is there a `World.class` present after recompilation of `Main.kt`?

Answer (score 0):

Your commands works fine if you use the normal directory structure, with a kotlin (or java) directory name for the source files root:

```
$ tree                                                                                                      
.
├── classes
└── src
    └── kotlin
        ├── hello
        │   └── Main.kt
        └── world
            └── World.kt

6 directories, 2 files
```

Weirdly enough the docs (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#directory-structure) don't seem to mention the top level kotlin/java directory, but just refer to it as the source root (fairly certain it was more explicit in the past). So what you are trying to do might be possible somehow, but it isn't something I've seen before.

Fyi, you also get the same error when just compiling Main.kt twice in a row, so it has nothing to do with modifying it.